Could we define a fifth arithmetic operation on real (or complex) numbers that is independent of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division?
The four basic arithmetic operations with real (or complex) numbers are addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. the first two being inverse operations and the last two being inverses of each other. The operation of exponentiation (and its inverse opeation of root extraction) are basically multiplications (and perhaps divisions). Am I right?
Now can we define a fifth arithmetic operation on the set of real (or complex) numbers that is independent of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division?

Multiplication and addition are related by the distributive law, so both operations are "dependent". Another "dependence" can be illustrated with an example. If $a\times b = 0$ then I know that either $a=0$ or $b=0$, and therefore $a+b = a$ or $a+b=b$. So, knowing $a\times b$ gave me information about $a+b$, meaning that $\times,+$ aren't independent. I think a proper definition of independence is required here.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer yes. Subtraction and division are far from being independent from multiplication or addition. Subtraction is addition with the additive inverse of a number and division is the multiplication with the multiplicative inverse of a number, which can be further simplified to adding something "multiplicative inverse of another number" times. OP please clarify :)

Well, how about defining independence to mean that the two binary operations are not the same function from $S \times S$ to $S$, where $S$ is our set in question?

I think I understand your question - in a really basic way if the we are not allowed to use the operator $\times$, we can still evaluate $a\times b$ using the operator $+$, and you want a new operator that cannot be replicated using a combination of existing operators, is that roughly it? My thoughts go immediately to Boolean logic where there are 16 basic "operators" but all of them can be expressed using "nand" operators so none are really "independent". Is that a fair summary of the question?

@RedFive that's right.

I don't think it is possible, and I wonder if it is possible to prove that such an operation cannot exist. I'm thinking of starting with a finite set... but no progress as yet.

There are uncountably many functions $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. Only a countable number of them can be obtained from combinations of addition, multiplication, exponentiation and their inverse operations (of which exponentiation, not being commutative,  has two: root extraction and logarithms). Thus there is a vast multitude of binary operations that are "independent" of these. But they are also not of any great interest, which is why you do not see much about them.
